# How would one do a multi-line Qt.binding() statement in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have a simple QML application where there is a Board (which is just a Rectangle named  'parentRect')  and a smaller child rectangle inside of it (named  'childRect').

I want to make it so whenever the **parentRect**'s *opacity* goes from **0**  to **1.0**, the opacity of **childRect** also changes the same amount for its final value,but I want the **childRect** to use  an OpacityAnimator  performs the animation of the opacity changing.

Here's the catch:

I'm trying to make it so that if the opacity is going from **0** to **1**, the OpacityAnimator's duration will be long, and if the opacity is going from **1.0** to **0**, the duration will be very short.

So far, here is what I've tried:

```
Rectangle {
    id: parentRect

    Rectangle {
        id: childRect
        opacity: parentRect.opacity
        visible: true
        property int index: 10
        Behavior on opacity {

            OpacityAnimator {
                duration: Qt.binding(function () {
                    if (parentRect.opacity === 0) {
                        return (50 * (index + 2))
                    } else {
                        return (2 * (index + 2))
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

After executing the code, I get the following error:

> qrc:/main.qml:138:47: Invalid use of Qt.binding() in a binding
>   declaration.

### Does anybody have any idea as to why my Qt.binding property is invalid?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error with the code you shared .. it runs without errors?

Comment: I included the error message at the bottom.. The code I provided is a minimal part of the code.. do you want the whole thing?    It does continue to run after the error messages pop up

Comment: If this minimal code is _not enough_ to reproduce the issue, then it might be difficult _at least for me_ to go any further

Comment: Also kindly check the shared part again, it seems missing a closing brace by the bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only use `Qt.binding()` when making an imperative binding, that is when you do `someProp = Qt.binding(someFoo)`, which unlike a regular assignment will bind the property value to an expression.

In your case you need to use the regular declarative binding syntax. If it is too complex for a single line, it can be written as a function, save for the "header" part.

```
someProp: {
  if (cond) {
     return val1
  } else {
     return val2
  }
}
```

If you so chose. Since in your case you could simply use the ternary conditional operator:

```
duration: parentRect.opacity ? (50 * (index + 2)) : (2 * (index + 2))
```

Or even:

```
duration: (index + 2) * (parentRect.opacity ? 50 : 2)
```

Comment: SO its the QML parser thats breaking things... I see...  wouldnt the ternary conditional operator examples simply assign whatever value results from the equations and not change dynamically?

Comment: No it won't, that's the canonical way of doing bindings in QML, the `Qt.binding()` function exists only for corner cases. Every property with notification will cause the expression to be reevaluated upon change, and furthermore, you will get a warning if you use a property without notification in a binding expression.

Comment: Very well written answer!

Comment: @dtech "you will get a warning if you use a property without notification" unless marked as constant